# Access the reports on Jasper Server through URLs embedded in JSP of my application

Tags: java, jsp, jasper-reports, jstl, jasperserver

I am a begginer in report generation using jasper report server. I want to show reports deployed in jasper server in my web application. 
I have read this article :
http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/embedding-using-http-api

I am doing this for self learning only so there is no issue of security.

So far i have done :
I made a web application and in my JSP i am using the following to embedding reports in JSP :

```
 <c:import url="http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&standAlone=true&_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=%2Freports%2FGraphD&reportUnit=%2Freports%2FGraphD%2FMainReport1&j_username=jasperadmin&j_password=jasperadmin" />
```

I have downloaded a theme and uploaded to jasper server and made it active, so as to remove header and jaspersoft logo etc.

Now when I run my application through tomcat, In browser it keeps reloading and nothing appears.

Note : If i dont pass username and password as parameters in request then jasper server login page appears but when i try to login , error is displayed : j_spring_security_check, The requested resource is not available.

I don't understand what i am doing wrong. :'(

Please Help.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the similar issue..., can someone help me here .. I am using jasperserver 6.3.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44554340/accesing-all-reports-in-a-folder-on-jasper-server-using-react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this maybe.
`<c:import var="data" url="http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&standAlone=true&_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=%2Freports%2FGraphD&reportUnit=%2Freports%2FGraphD%2FMainReport1&j_username=jasperadmin&j_password=jasperadmin"/>

<c:out value="${data}"/>`

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply..
i tried it now my page is opening with following :


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html> <head> <title>Jaspersoft: MainReport1</title> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> <!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/> --> <link rel="shortcut icon" href='/jasperserver/_themes/8BADFB3E/images/favicon.ico' />
........
..........
</html>

plz help

Comment: Well yeah, that's what <c:import does, it retries the output of that page and then prints it, that's what you wanted, yes?

Comment: Actually I want to open the URL specified there. for example if i give "www.google.com" in URL then it should open google web page not page with the tags. I also added "escapeXml=false" with "c out" but now i am back to where i was. i.e page keeps reloading. :(

Comment: I found another way. I used iframe tag and now its working :)

Comment: Ah, okay! Glad you fixed your issue